# HTTPS POST request sent in plaintext?

Tags: java, http, ssl, post, https

So I've recently implemented an SSL cert on my website for use in a program. *The issue I'm having here is that POST data sent by the program to the website is sent in plain text*, this is a REALLY big issue as you can imagine.
All that being said I have looked at other stack overflow posts and implemented their solutions however they don't seem to be working for me in the slightest. Any help is greatly appreciated!

How I'm calling the post request:

```
HttpClientFactory.sendPOSTRequest("https://www.somefakeurl.com/script", "version=7&username=SensitiveData&password=SensitiveData")
```

Here is how I'm sending the POST request:

```
public static String sendPOSTRequest(String URL, String data) throws Exception {
    String req = "sendPOSTRequest(" + URL.replace("https://www.somefakeurl.com", "") + ")";
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    SSLContext sslctx = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

    //See below for information on TmN...
    sslctx.init(null, new X509TrustManager[] { new TmN() }, null);

    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslctx.getSocketFactory());
    URL url = new URL(URL);

    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
    // con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
    // "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setDoOutput(true);

    // Basically just makes sure the data given is URLEncoded...
    if (data != null && !StringUtils.isWhitespace(data)) {
        String[] array0 = data.split("&");
        for (int i = 0; i < array0.length; i++) {
            String[] array1 = array0[i].split("=");
            try {
                array1[1] = URLEncoder.encode(array1[1], "UTF-8");
                array0[i] = String.join("=", array1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error on: " + array0[i]);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        data = String.join("&", array0);
    }

    OutputStream wr = con.getOutputStream();
    wr.write(data.getBytes());

    con.connect();
    if (con.getResponseCode() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            baos.write(line.getBytes());
        }
        br.close();
    }
    con.disconnect();

    //Print and return the request
    String res = new String(baos.toByteArray());
    req += (" = " + res + "\n");
    System.out.println(req);
    return res;
}
```

And here is the Trust Manager I'm using. (I know the name is unconventional, that's temporary):

```
   public class TmN extends X509ExtendedTrustManager{
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
    }

    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
    }

    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return new X509Certificate[0];
    }

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1, Socket arg2) throws CertificateException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1, SSLEngine arg2) throws CertificateException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1, Socket arg2) throws CertificateException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1, SSLEngine arg2) throws CertificateException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

And last but not least here is my proof. This was captured using Wireshark:
[image: Wireshark Capture (Somewhat Sensitive data redacted)]

Update:
So i think this specific post request is working properly,  wireshark can no longer find the url ending that I was searching with before however a different request,  on the same domain but different /page ending is still not encrypted.  They're both using the same function described above and format the data in the same way. What am I missing here?

Comment: Is https supported on server side? E.g. whether the request is secured once you send it from a browser?

Comment: Possibly not? I mean when I access the webpage in a browser it gives the all-ok. I am using PHP for the script so is there something special I need to do there?